# Sharing connection string between two separate windows forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a line of Windows Forms applications.  I am building the functionality of an options menu using the application settings tools to keep persistent data and settings.  In addition, all applications will allow the user to connect to a database and query data.  I am trying to find out a way to put a databse section in the options to allow the user to test and set database options.  When set I want the same settings to show up or sync with another application at runtime or when the next time another app is opened.

So far I have been thinking about using the windows registry, or making a project with application settings and adding it to all applications.  I also read about using a machine config file.  I am not too sure on what is the best or how this would all work when the applications are deployed.

The sharing of settings and/or values is not limited to just a connection string, but any data that may be useful to keep concurrent with all applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can open config files from any place with the ConfigurationManager. With this you can define a central configuration in a directory known to all your applications. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms134269%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I was going to suggest this approach, as well.  I would add that you should consider IsolatedStorage for the location of your "global" config file.  Ref:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3ak841sy(v=vs.100).aspx#isolated_storage_locations

Answer (score 0):

In this case I use SqlServer express, the best free DataBase.
In the App.config add this code

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="User ID=sa;Password=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=DATA_BASE_NAME;Data Source=XXXX\SQLEXPRESS"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In a Static Class of your application add this method

```
public static SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            string conn = string.Empty;
            conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection aConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            return aConnection;
        }
```

When you have need of db connection you call method in this way

```
SqlConnection aConnection = getConnection();
```

Comment: Ok. Let's say I change this connection string at runtime.  In addition, other applications are going to use this connection string to connect to the same database.  Now, how can I manage to let other applications see or get this newly changed connection string?

Comment: At runtime you can use this strategy for change connectionstring:   `SqlConnection aConnection = new SqlConnection("name=MyDataBase connectionString=User ID=sa;Password=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=DATA_BASE_NAME;Data Source=XXXXX\\SQLEXPRESS");`

Comment: I understand that as well.  I know I can build and assign the connection string at runtime.  My dilemma is when I need to save and allow that connection string to be seen by another application to be used to connect to a database.

Comment: In this case I think  can you save file in registry or in another file of your system and read this COnnectionString when have you need